# DocX - how to get the index of a paragraph or list?

Tags: c#, ms-word, novacode-docx

I am developing an application that needs to insert content from user input (including from a rich text editor) into a Word document. For this purpose I use the DocX library (http://docx.codeplex.com/). The library provides a very neat way of doing certain tasks and works great as long as you only need to insert content into an empty document.

However, the document I need to insert into is a template that already has some content. What I need is to be able to insert the user input after this content in the document. Like this:

Some default content here.

[This is were I want my content]

Some other default content here.

DocX has methods for inserting paragraphs and lists into a document:

```
using(var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(PathToTestFile))
{
    var doc = DocX.Load(stream); //will have two paragraphs
    var p = doc.InsertParagraph(); //adds a new, empty paragraph to the end of the document
    var list = doc.AddList(listType: ListItemType.Numbered); //adds a list
    doc.AddListItem(list, "Test1", listType: ListItemType.Numbered); //adds a listitem to the list
    doc.InsertList(list); //adds a list to the end of the document
}
```

A paragraph also has a method for inserting certain objects, like tables or other paragraphs either before og after itself:

```
//given a Paragraph p and another Paragraph newP:
p.InsertParagraphAfterSelf(newP);
```

Lists have the same method, but neither has the option of doing the same with other Lists (i.e. I cannot do the same as the above example with a list). For this purpose, I need the index of the paragraph or list in the document. This will allow me to use the insert methods that accepts an index as a parameter.

The DocX class has this (extracted from DocX source code: http://docx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DocX/DocX.cs):

```
// A lookup for the Paragraphs in this document.
    internal Dictionary<int, Paragraph> paragraphLookup = new Dictionary<int, Paragraph>();
```

This dictionary is internal, which means I cannot access it. I cannot, for the life of me, find any other way of finding the index, but it has to be a way since there are methods that needs this index. Has anyone encountered the same problem? A solution would be much appriciated!

Comment: Is there a tag in the paragraph that you are looking for the index of?

Comment: No, I was looking for a way to insert some content at a given index in the document, sort of like you would insert something into a specific array index. However, I ended up putting my "default" content into headers and footers, thus solving my initial problem. Still, the initial question of how to use the "InsertSomething" methods that accept an index parameter, is not answered..

Comment: You can use `Paragraph p = doc.Paragraphs[0];` to get an index and then `p.InsertParagraphAfterSelf(newP);`. `doc.Paragraphs` is a list of the documents `Paragraphs`. I'm still not sure what you were trying to achieve. Inserting a `Paragraph` after a number of `Paragraphs`? I'm glad you found your way around your issue.

Comment: It's true that you can access the Paragraphs collection. However, from what i can remember (It's been a while since I worked on this), this collection is of ALL paragraphs in the document, including headers, footers, list items etc. But frankly, I think that my case was sort of an edge case and that the way I solved it was better than what I was trying to do. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: @KristianJohannessen did you find a solution for this problem? if yes can you please share it with me. thank you

Comment: @wandos: I went with another solution. Instead of having the template document with some content at the top and bottom and then trying to insert in between, I just made a header and a footer in the document. DocX handles these seperately, so with this, I can just insert the content sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you are asking is to edit your template document in Word and insert a bookmark into it where you want to add content.  You can then use:

```
document.InsertAtBookmark("Content to be added", "bookmarkname");
```

to insert the content.

Comment: Yes, this would also work. I actually used bookmarks for inserting content at different locations in the header of the document. Using a header allowed me to insert the content by just adding paragraphs. But if a header doesn't cover your needs, bookmarks would be great. So marking as answer!